# How to redirect to the first configured login module in authsource when I access the SimpleSAMLphp core login page?

Tags: php, single-sign-on, simplesamlphp

I'm setting up a SimpleSAMLphp server as IdP. In my `authsources.php` I have configured 3 auth modules: `multiauth:MultiAuth` , `saml:SP` and a custom one based on SQLAuth module.

When I access the default simplesamlphp login page: `examample.com/simplesaml/module.php/core/login` I'm presented withe the 3 auth options.

What I want is when I access that login page,it should redirect to one of the modules login page directly, for example to `multiauth:MultiAuth` which is `/multiauth/selectsource.php`

I can't redirect directly because it asks for an `AuthState` parameter, this is my problem.

Answer (score 0):

In `metadata/saml20-idp-hosted.php`, you need to supply an `auth` paramater which specifies the authentication source you wish you use for the IdP, i.e. if you've defined a `multiauth:MultiAuth` authentication source in `config/authsources.php` as in the [example for that module](https://simplesamlphp.org/docs/stable/multiauth:multiauth):

```
'example-multi' => array(
    'multiauth:MultiAuth',
    ...
```

then for your IdP your `metadata/saml20-idp-hosted.php` should include something like:

```
'__DYNAMIC:1__' => [
  'host' => '__DEFAULT__',
  'privatekey' => 'example.org.pem',
  'certificate' => 'example.org.crt',
  'auth' => 'example-multi',
],
```

This will specify the default authentication source for this IdP.